# Hide row of a table on click of a button present in every row. Showing the same row in other empty table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have two  tables. One table contains data and other is empty. On click of a particular field present in every row, I want that row gets hidden and simultaneously get shown in empty table.

---

Html table I used have this type structure: 
I want rows to move to and fro on click of a `<span>@<span>`

```
  <table class='table1' id='frm1'>
    <tr>
    <th>
    Name</th>
    <th>
    Address</th>
    <th>
    Amount
    </th>

    </tr>
    <tr id="one">
    <td><span class="s1">@</span>
    John

    </td>
    <td>
    California
    </td>

    <td>
    $4000</td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="two">
    <td><span class="s1">@</span>
    tedd
    </td>
    <td>
    California
    </td>

    <td>
    $4000</td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="three">
    <td><span class="s1">@</span>
    John

    </td>
    <td>
    florida
    </td>

    <td>
    $8000</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <div class='text'></div>
    <div class='frm'>
    <table id='frm2'>
        </table>
```

`

---

jQuery code I used:

```
$('.s1').click(function(){$(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#frm2').end().end().hide();});


$('.s1').click(function () {

$("frm2 tr").attr('id', function() {return $(this).attr('id')});
alert($("frm2 tr").attr('id'));
});/*tried to set the id's of table 1 as id's to table 2*/
```

I want to move the rows to and fro. I am unable to have a reference to moved row

Comment: should it be in the same position?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to create a panel interface and move rows to-and-fro? Do you want to have a reference to the "moved" row so that you can "put it back" to the original table?

Comment: @arjuncc-yes i want the row to be seen in empty table at same position as it was in first table.

Comment: @Ejay-Yes I am trying exactly what yoy  said.Please help

Answer (score 0):

this is the rough code that'll achieve what you're describing

```
$('.particular_field').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#empty_table').end().end().hide();
})
```

**UPdate**
the accompaied markup

```
 <table id="table1" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="particular_field" value="click me" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="particular_field" value="click me" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="particular_field" value="click me" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="particular_field" value="click me" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table id="empty_table"></table>
```

Comment: -Thanks for the answer.I just copied this answer ,but on click of button,nothing happened.Can you guide me where I go wrong.

Comment: the code uses jQuery. And you'll need to put the code inside a doucment ready block like this. `$(document).ready(function(){/**code here**/})`. To get more accurate answers (or let us make more accurate assumptions), please post some code that you've tried (been requested already in comments).

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to click on a row from a table and put it on the other empty table, 
and viceversa, check this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nashio/MXKD3/1/

```
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", "table tr", function(){
    if( $(this).closest("table").hasClass("table1") ) {
        $(".table2 tbody").prepend($(this));
    } else {
        $(".table1 tbody").prepend($(this));
    }
});
});

Table Source
<table class="table1">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>John</td><td>Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Steve</td><td>Thomas</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Table Target
<table class="table2">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```